# Combining data sets

Tags: sql-server

I have two datasets that I'm not quite sure how to combine.

My first dataset and results(screenshot):

```
declare @start date, @end date
set @start = '6/1/2020'
set @end = '6/8/2020';

WITH Dates
     AS (SELECT [Date] = @START
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
         FROM Dates
         WHERE Date < @END)
     SELECT [Date] 
          , [Day] = DATENAME(dw, date)
    into #temp
     FROM Dates 
     OPTION(MAXRECURSION 50)
```

[image]

My second dataset and results:

```
select 
        Sunday =    len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 1, 20), '0', '')), 
        Monday =    len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 21, 20), '0', '')),
        Tuesday =   len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 41, 20), '0', '')),
        Wednesday = len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 61, 20), '0', '')),
        Thursday =  len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 81, 20), '0', '')),
        Friday =    len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 101, 20), '0', '')),
        Saturday =  len(replace(substring(convert(varchar(700), restricted_time, 2), 121, 20), '0', '')) 
FROM dbo.table 
where ID = ABC123
```

[image]

---

So what I need to do here is join based on the day of the week. For example, you see that Monday appears twice in the first data set, so I'd want to see the corresponding `5` for Monday in the second dataset show up twice, once for each occurrence of Monday. This example shows no diversity in data, but that's just the example I'm working with. Potential data could be anywhere from 0 through 10, but I need the numeric value to match up based on the day of the week. Here's what I want to see as a final result:

[image]

---

**SOLUTION:** Using unions, I was able to get my results. I dumped my second dataset into a temp table then wrote the following code and can then join against the temp table these results are placed in:

```
create table #count_formatted (Day varchar(10), Count int)
insert into #count_formatted
select 'Sunday' as Day, Sunday as count
from #count
union
select 'Monday', Monday
from #count
union
select 'Tuesday', Tuesday
from #count
union
select 'Wednesday', Wednesday
from #count
union
select 'Thursday', Thursday
from #count
union
select 'Friday', Friday
from #count
union
select 'Saturday', Saturday
from #count
```

Comment: Curious as to why you designed your table that way. I mean you could have two columns in your second dataset but you chose 5.

Comment: I couldn't think of another way to get it into a table. But I think I see what you're saying: a column for Day and a column for Count?

Comment: It could prove more flexible if you decide to add other values such as January, March, April, however, I was just asking out of curiosity. The way it is designed now you will always be required to unpivot your second dataset in order to join with other datasets. If the table was vertical this would not be a requirement.

Comment: That requirement definitely won't come into play, but astute point nonetheless. Is a pivot the only way to get my second dataset into that 2-column format?